# Magento Product URLs are not preserving URL parameters

Tags: magento-1.7, product-urls, 301-redirect

### **EDIT:**

This seems to have been caused by my CREARESEO extension. I had to uninstall to find that out since disabling the extension fooled me into thinking it was something else. I am working on locating the file that is interrupting Magento's default redirect, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

## Original Post

> How can I debug product redirect?
>
> I am tracking products in Google Shopping by appending
>   ?utm_source=google_shopping to the product URL. The problem is that
>   for some reason Magento will not allow URL parameters on product URLs.
>
> If my product url is /product-one.html?this=parameter it 301 redirects
>   to /product-one.html.
>
> *EDIT:* This only happens on product pages. If I append category or CMS page urls with URL parameters they work fine. That said, if my
>   category URL is /recipes and I type the old URL of
>   /recipes.html?this=parameter "?this=parameter" is lost.
>
> I have disabled my SEO extensions and when I do a var_dump of $request
>   on line 202 of /mage/core/controller/varien/router/standard.php it
>   knows that the requested URL has the parameters but it chooses not to
>   preserve them in the redirect.

```
    object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)#35 (26) {
      ["_originalPathInfo":protected]=>
      string(33) "/cinnamon.html"
      ["_storeCode":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_requestString":protected]=>
      string(33) "/cinnamon.html"
      ["_rewritedPathInfo":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "catalog"
        [1]=>
        string(7) "product"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "view"
        [3]=>
        string(2) "id"
        [4]=>
        string(4) "9736"
      }
      ["_requestedRouteName":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_routingInfo":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_route":protected]=>
      string(13) "ajaxaddtocart"
      ["_directFrontNames":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_controllerModule":protected]=>
      string(17) "FME_Ajaxaddtocart"
      ["_isStraight":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_beforeForwardInfo":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_paramSources":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "_GET"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "_POST"
      }
      ["_requestUri":protected]=>
      string(37) "/catalog/product/view/id/9736?this=ok"
      ["_baseUrl":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["_basePath":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_pathInfo":protected]=>
      string(35) "/ajaxaddtocart/product/view/id/9736"
      ["_params":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(4) "9736"
      }
      ["_rawBody":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_aliases":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["rewrite_request_path"]=>
        string(32) "cinnamon.html"
      }
      ["_dispatched":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["_module":protected]=>
      string(13) "ajaxaddtocart"
      ["_moduleKey":protected]=>
      string(6) "module"
      ["_controller":protected]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["_controllerKey":protected]=>
      string(10) "controller"
      ["_action":protected]=>
      string(4) "view"
      ["_actionKey":protected]=>
      string(6) "action"
    }
```

I modified the file mentioned above in hopes of forcing the parameters to be inherited by the rewritten rule to no avail.

```
 $requestedURL=$request->getRequestUri();
     $urlAliases=$request->getAliases();
     $urlAlias=$urlAliases['rewrite_request_path'];
     $parametersOfRequestedURL=strstr($requestedURL,"?",false);
     if($parametersOfRequestedURL){
         echo $newRequestURL=$urlAlias.$parametersOfRequestedURL;
         $request->setRequestUri($newRequestURL);
         var_dump($request);
         die;
         //$request->setRequestUri();
     }
```

**Removed HTACCESS as it seems to not be a part of the problem. Will provide if requested.**

Comment: Try commenting out this section `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/piwik/ ...` and retest

Comment: I have. It seems to be controlled by Magentos URL rewrite. I have disabled my SEO extensions and when I do a var_dump of $request on line 202 of /mage/core/controller/varien/router/standard.php it knows that the requested URL has the parameters but it chooses not to preserve them in the redirect.

Comment: What magento version are you using?

Comment: @r.s Magento 1.7 (see tags).

Comment: I just test on 1.7 and not having that issue

Comment: Right, this just started happening recently (but not so recent that I can track down the cause). It only happens to product URLs. Please see my updated comments. Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Also check your admin base url ... assuming that it is `www.domain.com`.. try `www.domain.com/?abc=123` and `domain.com/?abc=123` does both example product the same result

Comment: @R.S. This seems to have been caused by my CREARESEO extension. I had to uninstall to find that out since disabling the extension fooled me into thinking it was something else. I am working on locating the file within the extension that is interrupting Magento's default redirect, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the config.xml, more than likely this is done using a observer or rewrite

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the CREARESEO extension. I fixed it by doing the following:

Open /app/code/community/Creare/CreareSeoCore/Model/Observer.php

Find:

```
    public function forceProductCanonical(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_canonical_tag') && !Mage::getStoreConfig('product_use_categories'))
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('creareseocore/defaultseo/forcecanonical')) {
            // check for normal catalog/product/view controller here
            if(!stristr("catalog",Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()) && Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() != "product") return;
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $url = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, array('_ignore_category'=>true));
            if(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() != $url){
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url,301);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And replace with:

```
    public function forceProductCanonical(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_canonical_tag') && !Mage::getStoreConfig('product_use_categories'))
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('creareseocore/defaultseo/forcecanonical')) {
            // check for normal catalog/product/view controller here
            if(!stristr("catalog",Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()) && Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() != "product") return;
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $url = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, array('_ignore_category'=>true));
            // if there are GET parameters, add them to the url
            if($_GET) {
                $params = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', '|');
                $url .= $params;
            }
            if(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() != $url){
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url,301);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers.